# Flex Drag/Drop to exact coordinates of the Drag Proxy

Tags: drag-and-drop, flex4, coordinates

I added custom dragging and dropping in a flex (web) application and it all works fine except for a teeny weeny problem. The image been dropped drops a bit off the actual drag proxy. I want the image dragged and dropped to be in the exact place as the drag proxy. I dragging from a VBox to a Panel. I just cant seem to make the connection between the actual proxy coordinates and the dropped coordinates. Thanx a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but Im sure others are looking for this information. After a lot of debugging I have determined a way to make this work (Flex 4 ... 3 may be similar).
The issue is that the user can grab the original object anywhere to start the drag. When you drop the object you need to specify where it goes. To drop it perfectly you need to know where the user grabbed the object. I was unable to  find any reference to the "object to mouse" x,y coords in the DragEvent passed into the Drop Event handler. However this information IS provided in the original MouseEvent (localX, localY) passed in the Mouse Down handler. All you need to do is persist these coords (I stored them in the object being dragged as mouse offset variables). When the drop event happens just subtract them respectively from the DragEvents currentTarget mouseX and mouseY. For whatever reason I also needed to subtract 1 from both coords to get the drop perfect.
Here is a chunk of code to hopefully make it clearer.

```
// draggable  object mouse down handler
private function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
  // MenuObject is one of my custom objects
  var tempMenuObject:MenuObject = e.currentTarget as MenuObject;

  // The MenuObject contains its own custom drag proxy
  var tempProxy:Graphic = tempMenuObject.dragProxy;

  // HERE !!! --- persist the "mouse to object" coords
  tempMenuObject.mouseOffsetX = e.localX;
  tempMenuObject.mouseOffsetY = e.localY;

  DragManager.doDrag(e.currentTarget as IUIComponent, null, e, tempProxy);
}

// droppable containers drop handler
private function dragDropHandler(e:DragEvent):void {

  // HERE !!! --- set the dragged objects x y coords (needed to subtract ONE from both coords to get it perfect)
  e.dragInitiator.x = (e.currentTarget.mouseX - MenuObject(e.dragInitiator).mouseOffsetX) - 1;
  e.dragInitiator.y = (e.currentTarget.mouseY - MenuObject(e.dragInitiator).mouseOffsetY) - 1;

  // add the item to the container
  e.currentTarget.addElement(e.dragInitiator);
}
```

Hope it saves someone else some time ...